# Can C# StringReader.ReadLine() split a string on line breaks and keep empty lines?

Tags: c#, string, split, stringreader

In a C# application, I use the following to split a string on the line breaks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public static class StringUtil
{
  public static IEnumerable<string> splitByLines( this string src )
  {
    if ( src == null )
    {
      yield break;
    }

    using ( StringReader reader = new StringReader( src ) )
    {
      string line;
      while ( ( line = reader.ReadLine() ) != null )
      {
        yield return line;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I want to keep empty lines.  For example, when I split the following source string:

```
"Now is the time for all good men\r\nto come to the aid\r\nof their country.\r\n\r\nTo err is human,\r\nto really foul things up requires a computer.\r\n\r\nAble was I ere I saw Elba."
```

`StringReader.ReadLine()` skips over the double line breaks, and the result is just 6 substrings.

```
/* Undesirable result.  Empty lines are absent. */
"Now is the time for all good men"
"to come to the aid"
"of their country."
"To err is human,"
"to really foul things up requires a computer."
"Able was I ere I saw Elba."
```

I want the result to be 8 substrings, including the empty lines.

```
/* Desirable result.  Empty lines are kept. */
"Now is the time for all good men"
"to come to the aid"
"of their country."
""
"To err is human,"
"to really foul things up requires a computer."
""
"Able was I ere I saw Elba."
```

Comment: I [couldn't reproduce your complaint](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mfpm57)

Comment: ps; please name your method ***S***plitByLines; C# != Java

Comment: Your code should work as desired. If you retry and still get a different result. Please name the framework your compiling against.

Comment: Perhaps from wherever you are calling `splitByLines` you have a `string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)` check that causes empty lines to be filtered out?

Comment: Thanks Caius Jard and @Ralf.  You are correct that it does keep the empty lines.  I found the root problem elsewhere in my app that led me astray.